# Modify form field create annotation tool like Textbox, Checkbox, radiobutton, list for proper icons

Tags: pdftron

I am trying to create form field in webviewer(JavaScript) but every control(Textbox,List,Dropdown,Signature) look like same(rectangle) while we are creating forms, once we click "apply fields" it looks good but I want same UI while creating form.

Please see attached images

[image: Not able to distinguish between list and signature box]

[image: Expected while creating form]

Answer (score 0):

We've added the feature to our backlog to be worked on in the future. We don't have a timeline for when it will be available but if it does get worked on we'll let you know when it's available in an experimental build to test out and the estimated official release date.

If this is a critical new feature for you and you need a fixed timeline for this to be completed by, then we are sometimes able to do so as a custom engineering project. If you are interested in that, please fill in this form.
https://www.pdftron.com/form/professional-services/

Wanbo

Comment: I tried using example given on https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/annotation/custom-annotations/ but while exporting annotation it is giving imagedata I want to create custom FromField annotation do we have any work around?

Comment: For now, you may create your own UI for creating form fields. This [guide](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/forms/create-fields/#programmatically) is for how to create form fields and widget annotations programmatically. And this [guide](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/advanced-customization/) is for how to build your own UI.